# how to include node_modules when creating a standalone EXE ( to run a Node.js application) with battoexeconverter

Tags: node.js

I am working on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/make-exe-from-node-js-app?lq=1)

and the only answer that worked for me is the one  by alexjamesbrown (scroll down).

I could create an exe with [battoexeconverter](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/)  with a test node.js project.

But my real project uses several node_modules. How can I include these modules?

( I couldn't find an option to include directories. I just found the option to include files.
There are about 500 files in the required node modules and I don't want to manually include them one by one.)

Answer (score 0):

You could zip/rar the folder (node_modules.zip) and use a command-line utility to unzip it at runtime (BATTOEXE stores your files in the `%TEMP%` directory an deletes them when the app has been quit/stopped/ended).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial blog post on this here:

http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/create-a-standalone-exe-to-run-a-node-js-application/