# pack the nodejs and javascript code to one execute file

Tags: node.js

I hope to pack the nodejs(includes its installed module via npm) and javascript code to one execute file for different plateform(windows, osx, linux).

Is it possible or any solution?

Your comment welcome

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/make-exe-files-from-node-js-app

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can't really create an executable file for multiplatforms.  Each platform  has it's own packaging format to make it binary executable.  What you can do is to create a x.tar.gz file and expand it to your target platform.  I myself haven't done it but theoretically it's possible. Here is an example (assuming you're using GNU tar for all your platforms):

To pack it, do:

```
 tar cvzf nodeproject.tar.gz nodeproject
```

To expand, do

```
tar xvzf nodeproject.tar.gz
```