# Create a Self-Executing Node Server

Tags: node.js, server

Is it possible to to create a node program that can execute with the js "built in".

I know you can get the node binary from the website, but i was wondering if it was possible to package the node binary with the server code i create. So when i run the program, it will be a server running on localhost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make exe files from node.js app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/make-exe-files-from-node-js-app)

Comment: Note: Don't just read the accepted answer to the duplicate question. Read all of the answers. Specifically, for cross platform applications the best option to date is to use node-webkit (now called nwjs)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".