# How To Compile An Electron Application To A .exe

Tags: javascript, deployment, web-deployment, desktop-application, electron

I've been learning how to create applications in [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) and I need help compiling a simple project to a Windows executable. The program is a clone from this Github repo: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start. On the repo readme it shows how to run the program:

```
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
# Install dependencies
npm install
# Run the app
npm start
```

This works fine, but I can't figure out how to simply compile it. I've looked all over google, you would think that something as simple as deploying an application would be well known information.

Comment: Just run: npm install and then npm run dist --ia32

Comment: I found the following article to be helpful (using electron-builder): https://medium.com/how-to-electron/a-complete-guide-to-packaging-your-electron-app-1bdc717d739f

Answer (score 112):

You need to use [**Electron Packager**](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager).

**Install** it using:

```
# for use in npm scripts
npm install electron-packager --save-dev

# for use from cli
npm install electron-packager -g
```

And package or deploy using:

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=win32 --arch=x86_64
```

If you would like to keep it with the Electron Installation, see [**Application Distribution**](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-distribution.md#packaging-your-app-into-a-file).

**Update :**

Above command might throw an error

> Unsupported arch=x86_64 (string); must be a string matching: ia32, x64, armv7l, arm64, mips64el

Suggested to use one of the options from ia32, x64, armv7l, arm64, mips64el

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

Comment: I've tried that package, it doesn't work for me. I use an extra module that I installed with the npm install command named "electron-browser-window-options". When using "npm start" my program works fine, but after using electron-packager an error says "Error: Cannot find module 'electron-browser-window-options'".

Comment: Electron packager is the way to go. You should post a new question with your error description.

@Praveen: You may want to edit / extend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286924/how-to-deploy-an-electron-app-as-a-executable-or-installable-in-windows/31287581#31287581 instead, this seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @JensHabegger It's gonna be cyclic. 

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate but both this question and answer are MUCH better than ones linked to. It's a shame that this answer didn't solve @MitchMitchell's problem but it is the right solution for many people who may not find it if it doesn't have an accepted answer. I think it would be better for the community as a whole if this was rectified.

Comment: @Besworks We tried to talk to the mods and failed about merging the two questions. Unfortunately, that didn't work out.

Comment: I'm needing a standalone executable. Currently, electron-packager falls short on this requirement.

Comment: it just creates a portable folder. is there any way to create a true executable installer i.e. one `exe` file that actually installs the program to a directory???

Comment: Try electron-builder, see this youtube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J63H1coQedA.