# How does Visual Studio Code compile their source into an .exe File? (Windows)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, compilation

Here's the source of VSC, which is primarily written in NodeJS: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

I'd really like to know what method they used to compile their JS source code into an executable file.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's Electron who is responsible for this, but i am sure they use Electron.

There are some packagers for Electron who can do that. (I am not sure if they use one of those, though. I have no experience with Electron, but [here you have some reference for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615892/10473393))