# How can make my React.js project downloadable on Desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, electron

Good afternoon all,

I am a new programmer and I recently started following a music-player tutorial, and am experiencing a couple of issues with it.

Project Overview:

As previously described, it is a music-player project made with create-react-app. The objective is to click the image of the song of your choosing, and for the song to be played for you.

The songs are saved as mp3’s in a folder named music. The music folder is located in the src directory. Each song is assigned to its given song image (as you’ll see on the code I provided below). Then the songs/images are wrapped in an  list element.

**Now that I've got the project details out the way I wanted know how I can make a React.Js application downloadable on the desktop. Is there any way?**

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615837/how-to-compile-an-electron-application-to-a-exe

Comment: I've heard of electron, however what I do know of it is that you need to do a ``npx create-electron-app`` command to execute it. hat if i copied and pasted my react code on it, that it would not compile.But if this is not true, how can you integrate it in react?

Comment: Electron, among other things, renders webpage code (such as a React app) in an ordinary application window - it's quite natural