# Export Electron app to single exe with all dll and other files included

Tags: javascript, electron, exe

I’m looking to package all of my app into one file.exe that doesn’t need other files and folders to run, so that my users can copy this file.exe and have everything they need and can move it to anywhere on their computer and still run it. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into electron-forge? https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge

Comment: yes, but I have no idea how to use it, and the docs are confusing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy an Electron app as a executable or installable in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286924/how-to-deploy-an-electron-app-as-a-executable-or-installable-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I used a package called [electron-winstaller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-winstaller)

This takes a already packaged installer with all the `.dll` files and puts them into a single `.exe`

To package you can use this script:

```
var installer = require('electron-winstaller');
var path      = require('path');

console.log("packaging into a exe...");
resultPromise = installer.createWindowsInstaller({
    appDirectory:    './AppName-win32-ia32',
    outputDirectory: './installers',
    exe:             'AppName.exe',
    setupExe:        'FinalExeName.exe',
    noMsi:           true,
    iconUrl:         'IconUrl',
    setupIcon:       'IconPath'
});

resultPromise.then(function () {
    console.log("Installer created");
    require('electron').app.quit();
});
```

[electron-winstaller docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-winstaller)