# electron-builder, how to set node environmental variables

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

The Node.js environment in Windows can be set before the server is started, like this:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

That `NODE_ENV` parameter can be used in Node.js or electron by `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

But when I build electron using `electron-builder`, like this:

```
electron-builder build --windows
```

How do I set the environmental variables?

---

**Update:**

May be I cannot pass a fixed environment variable to an executable by `electron-builder`.

Maybe you can only manually load an environment file, modify it when you package it, or preset the parameters to the `dev` state. When there is no state, it is `production`.

Comment: Similar question that has a useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656933/put-env-file-while-building-in-electron-packed-app/76404441

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an environment variable to be set on runtime you can either set them manually or use other tools like `dotenv` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

But the easiest way is to set them at runtime when running the binaries. You can use either a batch script (If windows) for example:

```
setlocal
set NODE_ENV=production
.\your-binaries.exe
endlocal
```

*Note*: setlocal prevents the variable leaking any further.

The one-liner version could be `set NODE_ENV=production && .\binaries.exe`

Under linux works the same way: set variable then run.

Comment: What does “CLI usage” mean? I created a `electron-builder.env` file in the current dir and input `NODE_ENV=production`, and builder electron, It's not work. I try to working in `electron .` to start and test show `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`, It's undefined.

Comment: @AlbertChen CLI ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface ) means that this file is read by the command `electron-builder` at runtime, `electron` will not read it.

Comment: I was try to build electron by `electron-builder` command , like this: `electron-builder build --windows`, but it's not work. I need other parameter for the command?

Comment: @AlbertChen Try to put it in the root of source files, like in this repository that is used as example in the docs https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand/tree/master/test (See `.env`)

Comment: I was put `electron-builder.env` file in root of source files(same as `package.json` path or `electron-builder.json` path).

Comment: @AlbertChen Wait, you want the variable to be defined at runtime in the built binaries? Because if it's that, the answer has nothing to do with electron-builder.

Comment: runtime?built binarie? I went the `env` variable is working in release Setup(.exe) file by `electron-builder` builder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186836/discussion-between-sigmasoldier-and-albert-chen).

Comment: It's stated in directly in the documentation. Create a `electron-builder.env` file and put the variables inside. The `electron-builder.env` file should reside in the root of the folder, i.e. same folder as where `package.json` is, or where `electron-builder.json` is (if you are using it). When you package the app using the command line interface, meaning run `electron-builder` to package the files rather than using it as a library. However, it does NOT work. If any one gets it to working, please do comment.

Comment: Because this answer got edited there's some interesting information that was lost but relevant. The answer initially quotes *"Env file `electron-builder.env` in the current dir (example). Supported only for CLI usage."* (which is from [electron builder docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#environment-variables-from-file)). The CLI usage is confusing - what they mean is that you have to use the CLI when running electron builder to include the `electron-builder.env` file.

Comment: how is that batch script executed when packaged with the electron app?

Comment: @PabloPazos I think you have to package the .bat file along the packaged app, so it can't be embedded inside, if that's why you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting this in the hopes that it helps other people in my situation. I have three environments (development, staging, and production), and I wanted my Electron *main process* to be aware of which environment it was running on.

Now, for development it's quite easy to expose an environment variable to Electron inline using the CLI:

```sh
export NODE_ENV=development && electron desktop/main.js
```

Then, Electron's main process can access this environment variable like so:

```js
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```

However, being able to distinguish between the staging and production environments was slightly trickier. My staging and production environments are both packaged and deployed using `electron-builder`, with `package.json` scripts like so:

```
"desktop-build": "webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.prod.js && electron-builder --config config/electron.config.js",
"desktop-build-staging": "webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.staging.js && electron-builder --config config/electron.config.js",
```

*NOTE: The webpack configs above expose configs to the renderer process (website), but not the main process.*

So my solution to expose the environment to the Electron *main* process for staging and production was as follows:

1. Set `NODE_ENV=staging` or `NODE_ENV=production` to `electron-builder` via command line invocation:

   ```sh
   # Production
   export NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.prod.js && electron-builder --config config/electron.config.js

   # Staging
   export NODE_ENV=staging && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.staging.js && electron-builder --config config/electron.config.js
   ```
2. In my `electron.config.js` file (configs for `electron-builder`) use the `extraMetadata` parameter ([docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html#configuration)) to inject a variable into my `package.json`:

   ```js
   extraMetadata: {
       isProduction: Boolean(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'),
   },
   ```
3. Then you can access that from your Electron main process:

   ```js
   // This variable is injected into package.json by electron-builder via the extraMetadata field (specified in electron.config.js)
   const {isProduction} = Boolean(require('./package.json'));
   ```

Comment: Part 1. of this answer will not work. When the main process runs, on a separate machine from where it was built, it will different environment variables. Especially in this case it will not have the `NODE_ENV` var. The *environment* variables are specified by the environment where the application is running, not when it is built.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this through [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) and electron-builders' [`extraResources`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources)

Firstly create a `.env` file at the root of your project next to the `package.json`.

```ini
MY_VAR=foo
```

In the `package.json` include

```json
  "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      ".env"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

In your `main.js` you need to use the [`path` option](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path) for `dotenv`. [Hat tip to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76404441/327074) for pointing me towards `dotenv`.

When in dev mode, before the app is packaged, then `dotenv` will pick up the `.env` in the root. However when packaged you have to specify the path to where `extraResources` puts it which is in `process.resourcesPath`. You can use [`app.isPackaged`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appispackaged-readonly) to tell whether we are in dev mode or in the packaged application.

```js
require('dotenv').config({
    path: app.isPackaged
        ? path.join(process.resourcesPath, '.env')
        : path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env'),
})

// now process.env includes all the values from the `.env` file.
const foo = process.env.MY_VAR
```

Note: Just by having the `.env` in the root, [electron-builder picked up the `process.env` vars](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#environment-variables-from-file) within my application, but it seems that `main.js` is a special case that has to be handled differently.

Comment: here how can i pass .env.staging for my staging build and .env.production for my production build @icc97

Comment: @JIMMYJACOB I'm not sure if you can - the `extraResources` is hard coded and you can't specify it via an npm script. The only thing I can think of would be to generate a different `.env` file during your deployment. So for production deployment you rename `.env.production` to `.env` and for staging you rename `.env.staging` to `.env`