# Put env file while building in electron packed app

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I need to put a `.env` file into a packed app while building, then attach variables from the `.env` to `process.env`. I put the `.env` in the same directory as the `package.json` and it works when I start electron from npm. It won't work when I build a MacOS app and start it (it seems as though the `.env` file is lost).

My `main.js` starts a java backend, so I provide environment variables:

```js
// This works in npm start, but not for packed app
process.env.MY_VAR = dotenv.config().parsed.MY_VAR;

this.serverProcess = require("child_process").spawn(
    "/usr/bin/env",
    ["sh", dirname + "/server/bin/embedded"],
    { env: process.env });
```

My case is:

- Generate `.env` and put it to electron folder (it generates automatically by build system)
- Build electron and pack electron

```bash
electron-builder --mac --publish never
```

- Start MacOS App
- Packed app should run java with the provided environment (from `.env`)

Is there an example or best practices how to put environmental variables while package building?

Comment: One thing that I have learned is that the `.env` file access is different than for the application `.env` file access. So if I just include a `.env` file in the root of my project next to the `package.json` then it will get picked up in the application. However this still doesn't work for `main.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotenvExpand` did the trick.

```
const dotenvExpand = require("dotenv-expand");

if (process.resourcesPath) {
    dotenvExpand.expand(dotenv.config({ path: path.join(process.resourcesPath, ".env") }));
}
```

Comment: Isn't `dotenv` enough?

Comment: How did you make sure that the `.env` file was in the `resourcesPath`?

Comment: @icc97 `dotenv` just loads a file into an object, while `dotenv-expand` loads an object into the environment (`process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`). To avoid unrelated stuff, I'm not checking the existance of `.env` file here.

Comment: thanks for your reply. `dotenv` does already put the vars into `process.env` ([*"Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env. "*](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#dotenv-)). `dotenv-expand` allows you to include env vars *within* your env vars for example `FOO=$BAR`.