# [Mac OS]: How to create an Electron application installer for Windows, but using a Mac?

Tags: electron

I have successfully built my first app on a Mac using atom and electron, but now I don't know how to get the app to Windows for other people to install.

Basically I don't know how to create an installer for Windows on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to know how to create a Windows install package (.exe or .msi) for an Electron app *for the situation when you are developing the app on Mac OS*.

There are multiple options; identify and choose a packaging solution that meets your needs.

---

**Electron-builder**

One of the available packagers for Electron is electron-builder, see documentation here:
https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build

There are limitations.

From the electron-builder documentation:

> On macOS/Linux you can build Electron app for Windows locally, except Appx for Windows Store

---

**Other options**

https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron#tools

Look at the great list of tools here for some additional packaging options.

For other options available to you, and some discussion, take a look at the answers to this related question: [How to deploy an Electron app as a executable or installable in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286924/how-to-deploy-an-electron-app-as-a-executable-or-installable-in-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I use electron-packager, and I can build a .exe file perfectly on a macos, I think what he is asking is how to build a "Windows Installer", not an exe file, but a msi file, that opens an installer

Comment: Hey @Jeremiah I agree, as my answer states: ... how to create a Windows install package (.exe or .msi) ... when ... developing the app on Mac OS. The tools I mention do provide for .msi install scenarios. For example https://www.electron.build/configuration/squirrel-windows see the msi boolean option documented here msi Boolean - Whether to create an MSI installer. Defaults to false (MSI is not created).