# Can I create a windows exe from a react project

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project.  I would like to create a downloadable windows exe.  I can do it with a node server using Zeit pkg but I don't know how to do that (or something similar) with react.

I have tried Zeit pkg.  Not seeing many other options.

Comment: Look into Electron: https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Yes, Electron and a couple of other tools to generate the .exe - as listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31287581/1424833

Answer (score 9):

Electron is the way to go, is very simple to use like cordova, here's a hello world example:

Install

```sh
npm install -g electron
```

Create a main.js file and add this:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // 'public' is the path where webpack bundles my app
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/public/index.html`);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

Finally run the app:

```sh
electron main.js
```

The hardest part is actually creating the installer, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-windows-installer/) for windows.

More info about electron [here](https://electronjs.org/). Hope it helps.