# Electron - Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: angular, electron, angular-cli, electron-builder

Evening,
I'm looking into using [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to package an existing angular2 build. I thought I had a dry run working but the actual packaging seems to be failing (see final step below) and I want to understand why. Here's what I'm doing...

**Create Project**
Use [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) to start a new project `ng new electron-ng2-cli --style=scss`

Install electron and [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)

**Edit package.json**
Make the following additions...
 `"main": "main.js"`

```
"build":
{
  "appId": "com.electrontest.testapp",
  "mac": {
    "category": "your.app.category.type"
  }
}
```

and add the following to the `scripts`...

```
"pack": "build --dir",
"dist": "build",
"electron": "electron main.js",
"postinstall": "install-app-deps"
```

**Create main.js**
I just copied the code from the [electron quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js). The only change I make is to the location of `index.html` which I set to `/dist/index.html`

**Amend base**
In `index.html` change `<base="/">` to `<base="./">`

**Pack code**
Run `ng build`. This puts all the packaged code in `/dist`

**Test Run**
Run `npm run electron`. This works fine. An Electron app fires up and I see the angular stuff running within it.

**Create App For Distribution**
Run `npm run pack` to create a packaged app. The packaging seems to go ok - I get a warning about a missing icon and a warning that my code is unsigned but I'm guessing they shouldn't be fatal?
The problem is that when I now run the app by double clicking in `Finder` I get an error in the console saying: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/<username>/Documents/development/electron-ng2-cli/dist/mac/electron-ng2-cli.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/index.html`

---

So, can anyone explain what is different between the packaged app that fails and the one that runs ok when I use `npm run electron`?

What can I do to fix this issue and get the app running correctly?

Thank you for making it to the end. This got longer than I wanted but I hope I explained myself ok. If you can help or give any pointers that would be great - many good vibes will be thought in your general direction :)

Cheers all

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It took a lot of trial and error but I got this working. There is a lot here that I don't totally understand, and much that might be pointless or bad practice and it might all fall down at the very next step but if, like me, you are just trying to get over the first hump then maybe something I found will help you.

I found the problem by [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523617/asar-how-to-unpack-a-asar-file) the `app.asar` file that `electron-builder` produces. Instead of containing the bundled code from my `dist` folder it contained all the project code (`*.ts *.scss` etc). The problem was just that the packing functions were packing up the wrong stuff.
The steps to get the right source into the final app are simple when you lay them out but my god they didn't half put up a fight! Starting from where I left off in my initial question I did the following...

*Remember that my project structure is the default one set up by angular-cli*

**Electron specific files**
I moved the `main.js` down into `src` and changed its name to `electron-main.js` just to stop any confusion with the `main.ts` that is already in there. I also changed the path it references back to `/index.html`.
Next I created a new application level `package.json` also in `src` and gave it the following content:

```
 {
  "name": "application-name",
  "description": "CLI app",
  "author": "Me me me",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "electron-main.js"
}
```

**angular-cli.json**
I changed the `outDir` to `build` purely because electron seems to output to `dist` by default and I wanted some separation at this stage. Then I addded `package.json` and `electron-main.js` to the `assets` array.

**Main package.json**
I removed the `"main":"main.js"` as it is apparently no longer needed here. In `scripts` I changed the test command to `electron build` to point it at the build folder where the bundled code will be.
Finally, I went to the `build` field and added the following content:

```
"directories": {
  "buildResources": "build",
  "app": "build"
}
```

Seems pretty obvious now. This just tells the compiler where to look for the assets that will make up the final app. It was defaulting to the working directory and that was my problem.

Using this setup I can now run `ng build` to bundle my project into the `build` folder along with the `electron-main.js` and `package.json`.
This done I can run `npm run electron` to quickly launch a test app or `npm run pack` to build an app that can be launched from `Finder`.

Boom. Job done. I'll be back here in ten minutes with another annoying question I expect. Gotta love the dev these days :)

Comment: is there another way to work around this than doing it this way?

Comment: You give a great practice to build an electron app. But I can't find how to solve the problem  'Not allowed to load local resource' when try to load some local files. How can you fix this?

Comment: Is this still valid with most up-to-date angular? I don't know what you mean by "Finally, I went to the build field and added the following content:

"directories": {
  "buildResources": "build",
  "app": "build"
}"

Comment: @popClingwrap this solution didn't work for me.
I am able to generate exe with the help of electron + angular 10+ and also able to install it. But when i run the installed application it is getting blocked by trend micro antivirus, where in other system the antivirus is not installed that let me use that installed application.
I have googled and tried multiple solutions but neither of worked.

Answer (score 79):

**Problem may be the invalid path in `main.js`**, correct it if necessary

[image]

Comment: D'oh! That was silly... (That moment when 25 other folks did the same mistake haha)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. i'm very new to EletronJS. I tried almost all the possible way to solve this issue. But after viewing your opinion. I checked my base set up & found, I didn't put any name of my workspace. So simply put a name & edit ```testBuild.code.workspace``` and restart VS code. All done.

Comment: This was my case, i had typo in my directory :)

Comment: @WasiF this solution didn't work for me. I am able to generate exe with the help of electron + angular 10+ and also able to install it. But when i run the installed application it is getting blocked by trend micro antivirus, where in other system the antivirus is not installed that let me use that installed application. I have googled and tried multiple solutions but neither of worked.

Comment: Remember to rebuild your code after changing that, otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 23):

In case this helps anyone, the issue I was having was I had the path set using **process.cwd()**:

```
win.loadURL(`file://${process.cwd()}/dist/index.html`);
```

Which when packaged is not correct since the the main.js file is not in the root anymore. Changing to **__dirname**:

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
```

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 18):

Just change the BrowserWindow' options:

`new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    webSecurity: false
  }
})`

If window's url points to a remote source, like http://..., browser will not allow to load local resource, unless you set the options above.

Comment: Turning off security is *never* an answer

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter The problem is the default security options of a browser not allowed to load local resource, but Electron is not just a browser. Do you have another way?

Comment: From Electron docs: [Do Not Disable WebSecurity](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#5-do-not-disable-websecurity).

Comment: A counter view to all the comments above: Electron is a great GUI for desktop apps, and many apps have no ability to show anything external. It's all just "my code", and so all this "security" absolutism is misplaced and unwelcome. Put another way: my code can *access your whole hard drive*. My code does not show web content. It has no way of running someone else's code. For apps like that, all of these "security" warnings and features add nothing but hassle.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and my mistake was the `win.loadURL` was not correct (loadURL tried to load a file who doesn't exist).
Be sure your url is correct otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me on linux

```
 newWindow.loadFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
```

you can add this to view the directory of your main.js and from there navigate to the index.html.
`console.log(__dirname)`

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a `'.'` here. You only need to put relative path instead of absolute path.

```js
win.loadFile('./dist/index.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and I solved it by looking for the path .
 for exemple my error message is

```
file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/fetni%20mohamed/electron/app/elctronapp/dist/electron-app/index.html
```

looking in the dist folder I found a folder named electronapp but in the path it's electron-app so by changing the folder name it worked.
you can change the output path in the angular.json, and specifiy the same name as in the path shown in the error

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently running Angular12+ and this simple solution worked for me:

```
"build": {
    //config
    "directories": {"output": "release/"},
    //more config
}
```

With this, the packed app with the installer is now created in release/ folder, and now I can install it. The dist/ folder remains, because that's where Angular builds the app.

Answer (score 1):

[popClingwrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41173679) answer worked for me, but I wanted to keep the original project structure (keeping package.json at top level). As popClingwrap stated my app.asar file contained the not compiled files of my angular application. The content of the build folder was ignored.

So my approach look at little bit different.

*I used the default project structure provided by angular cli.*

**angular.json**
I change the outputPath to "build", to avoide conflicts with the electron build dir.

```
"options": {
   "outputPath": "build"
}
```

**Electron specific files**

electron-main.js: I kept this file as is, at the top level of the project.

The pathname of the index.html was set to match the new build directory of angular.

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
  url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/build/index.html`)
  })
);
```

**Main package.json**
The most important change was done in this file. The "file" sections copies only the needed files to the electron-builder dir.

```
{
  ....
  "build": {
    ....
    "files": [
      "!.angular",
      "build/**",
      "!node_modules",
      "!src",
      "electron-main.js",
      "package.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

This did the trick from me without changing my default project structure.
Many thanks to popClingwrap who got me on the right track.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was very helpful for me.  In addition to this, I built my application for Mac (arm64), opened up the application (mac applications are like a folder, right-click -> Show Package Contents to see), and looked in: /Content/resources/app, which showed me what the working directory is when built.  The suggestions here about build setup combined with modifying my main.js for electron to point to the correct location solved my build issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem when i tried to build my app with electron-builder...

What worked for me was
in package.json file i built with ng build then runed  electron-builder

```
"scripts": {
 ...
"build-installer": "ng build --prod && electron-builder"
},
```

and in the index.html changed base href to

```
 <base href="">
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing `"private": true`, to `"private": false` in package.json. works for me.

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "ng build && electron .",
    "pack":"electron-packager ."
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^7.2.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "electron": "^10.1.5",
    "electron-packager": "^15.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is can also be thrown when index.html does not exist.

In my case, my build folder "dist" was being ignored by electron-builder and not packaged properly into /app.

[See this issue for more information](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1929)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this :

```
{
  "from": "../dist",
  "filter": ["**/*"]
}
```

into "files" section of electron-builder.json fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and by adding below code in "`build`" this is fixed:-

```
"files": [
    "**/*",
    "!**/*.ts",
    "!*.map",
    "!package.json",
    "!package-lock.json",
    {
      "from": "../dist",
      "filter": ["**/*"]
    }
],
```

Mainly

```
{
    "from": "../dist",
    "filter": ["**/*"]
}
```

And remove  "`extraResources`" if present.

And in winloadurl add dist like this:-

```
win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname,'../dist/index.html'));
```

I am using Electron-24, Node-18 and Angular-16

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was running npm run make script first ("make": "electron-forge make") before running npm build, however after I built it with "npm run build" and ran "npm run make" I was able to see my project running from exe file

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. This worked for me

```
// and load the index.html of the app.
  window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'), // important
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
    // baseUrl: 'dist'
  }));
```

Comment: url.format() just return an url string, makes no difference.

Comment: I have no clue. I have same doubts you have. but it worked.

Comment: This solves the problem because url.format is passing back a string how loadURL expects.  The solution above using ticks instead of single quotes works, but so should this.