# How to fix "Not allowed to load local resource" Node-JS

Tags: node.js, requirejs, electron

I am making an Electron app that when a button is clicked it creates a new window and loads HTML into it, but for some reason the HTML isn't loaded into it and when I toggle developer tools for the window it shows me in the console this error:

> "Not allowed to load local resource". It doesn't tell me  a specific line.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
const {BrowserWindow} = electron.remote;

// NewTODO window variable
let newTodoWindow;

// Function to call when "New todo" button is clicked
function NewTodo(){
  // Creates a NewTODO window
  createTodoWindow();
}

function createTodoWindow(){
  newTodoWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  newTodoWindow.loadFile("./newTodoWindow.html");
  newTodoWindow.setSize(400 , 400);
}
```

All it needs to do is that when createTodoWindow function is called(And it is called) it would create a new window and load the HTML to it, but it only creates the window without loading the HTML.
I am not sure why that goes like and I would really appreciate getting help.

Comment: If you get console errors, it's a good idea not to paraphrase them, but to show them verbatim (just copy-paste them, and then put them in your post the same way you put a block of code), and explain which line number maps to which line of code you're showing in your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron - Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130993/electron-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this error occurs when trying to require a file that doesn't exist and that's exactly what I tried doing, For some reason I changed the file I tried requiring and just forgot to require the file with the right name.