# Set image src with %2F in filename

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using javascript, I am setting the src property of an image object

```
    mainImage.src = filePath;
```

When filePath is something like C:\images\pink.jpg, I have no problems
But I found a bug where the filename is of the type:

```
    C:\images\uploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F1574322%2F0b0640a8-cfca-45fa-b1c7-2cfc9a97c146.jpg%2Ffull-fit-in__950x534.jpg
```

It seems that the %2F is read as a \ character and I end up with a net::ERR_FAILED error.
But the filename is literally uploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F1574322%2F0b0640a8-cfca-45fa-b1c7-2cfc9a97c146.jpg%2Ffull-fit-in__950x534.jpg.

Is there a way to set the src property of an image with filenames such as these without any error? I am setting this value in an electron project which means that chrome is being used to test.
Many Thanks

Comment: Are the image given this name structure in your code? It seems like the best option is to clean up the process that is creating these in the first place.

Comment: Did you tried to prepend `file:` to the filepath? Like this: `file://C:\images\uploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F1574322%2F0b0640a8-cfca-45fa-b1c7-2cfc9a97c146.jpg%2Ffull-fit-in__950x534.jpg`

Comment: Yes I did. Here is the full error: /C:/Projects/Javascript/photos/test/uploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F1574322%2F0b0640a8-cfca-45fa-b1c7-2cfc9a97c146.jpg%2Ffull-fit-in__950x534.jpg:1 GET file:///C:/Projects/Javascript/photos/test/uploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F1574322%2F0b0640a8-cfca-45fa-b1c7-2cfc9a97c146.jpg%2Ffull-fit-in__950x534.jpg net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 0):

encodeURI will do the trick.

```
let url = 'file:///c:/images/uploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F1574322%2F0b0640a8-cfca-45fa-b1c7-2cfc9a97c146.jpg%2Ffull-fit-in__950x534.jpg'

mainImage.src = encodeURI(url);
```

Comment: Thanks. The string resolves nicely but I get an error, maybe from electron which says:
[5464:0120/021413.476:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/igweo/OneDrive/Pictures/seamm_jasani.jpg", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@8eedfc19d05fc36b29e85714af178c99600e271e/&can_dock=true&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true (0)

Comment: It is coming from Electron, but this is another question, for your question i answered the correct answer, please create a new question with the new issue. you can check this answer it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130993/electron-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource please check my answer as the answer if you found it correct.