# Electron app shows blank screen when built with electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

As the title explains, i have a simple Electron app that loads a html page when started. Everything works fine, but if i try to build the project using electron-builder (`yarn dist`), the application shows nothing but a blank screen. Any idea of why this happens?

My project structure is the following:

```
-- e2e
-- dist
-- node_modules
-- src
   -- app
   -- assets
   -- environments
   -- index.html
-- editor.config
-- angular.json
-- broswerlist
-- karma.conf.js
-- main.js
-- package.json
-- package-lock.json
-- tsconfig.json
-- tslint.json
```

I also post my `main.js` and `package.json` files:

**main.js**

```
const electron = require("electron")
const {app, Menu, BrowserWindow} = require("electron")
const path = require("path")

let mainWindow

app.on('window-all-closed', e => e.preventDefault() )
app.on('ready', createWindow);

function createWindow() {

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width:1380,
    frame:false,
    closable: false,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    resizable: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })


  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();


  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
    protocol: "file",
    slashes: "true"
  }))

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "author": "me",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "7.1.8",
    "electron-builder": "^22.2.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "target": [
      "nsis"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "msal-electron-poc": "^0.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.21",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the value of `path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')` match what you expect?

Comment: I actually don't know. I am trying to load the html file built by angular and packaged by electron-builder, but i don't know its location and i cannot explore it since it's inside an asar file.

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524534/4711754) to explore the asar file but I think you need `path.join(__dirname, 'dist/whatever-your-app-name-is/index.html')`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Replace
path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')

//with
path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html')
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to load the source html file without the angular components working?

Comment: In case of Electron-builder, dist is the folder where application file appears and it is excluded from the build. In your case use some other name in place of dist after compiling the source code through angular CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. And was able to run electron on windows by running.
for windows:

```
vue-cli-service electron:build --mode development --windows
```

for Linux:

```
vue-cli-service electron:build --mode development --rpm
```

And check if there are some hidden errors or it just work after.