# electron + react + vite how to build correctly

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite

I'm trying to create a windows app with electron + react + vite, which is extremely faster and smaller. But I'm having problems compiling with electron-builder.
you can see entire code here...
https://github.com/collaxd/template-electron-react/tree/vite
So after build with some erros and open software on console you can see

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Colla/Desktop/Programming/electron/template-react-electron/dist/win-unpacked/resources/app.asar/public/build/index.html
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "template-react-electron",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"electronmon . \" \"vite\"",
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ build/ && vite build && electron-builder && cd dist && explorer ."
  },
  "build": {
    "target": "win",
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icon.png"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "electron": "^20.1.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.3.3",
    "electronmon": "^2.0.2",
    "vite": "^3.0.7"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      server: {
        open: false, // do not open the browser as we use electron
        port: 3333
      },
      build: {
        outDir: './build'
      }
    });
```

main.js (electron)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const { join } = require('path');

function createWindow() {
  // Create a browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: './public/icon.png',
    webPreferences: { preload: join(__dirname, 'preload.js') }
  });
  console.log();

  // Load correctly url
  const url = isDev ? `http://127.0.0.1:3333/` : `file://${join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html')}`;
  // const url = 'C:\\Users\\Colla\\Desktop\\Programming\\electron\\template-react-electron\\build\\index.html';
  win.loadURL(url);
  // Open the DevTools.
  isDev && win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

// app ready
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
// close all win
app.on('window-all-closed', () => process.platform !== 'darwin' && app.quit());
// etc
app.on('activate', () => BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0 && createWindow);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I found [this template on github](https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-react) and it really saves me a lot of setup work, you just run the script `npm create electron-vite` and it works, try it on both linux and windows (using electron-builder for distribution).

Comment: ty alot, but It uses typescripts wich I don't want to learn now :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe with your vite config, you can remove the "build" part of the path when loading the URL in electron:

```
  // Load correctly url
  const url = isDev ? `http://127.0.0.1:3333/` : `file://${join(__dirname, '..', 'index.html')}`;
```

vite should bundle both `main.js` and your react app in the `build/` directory, so adding it in the url to load from will target the wrong file. [You can also extract the contents of the app.asar generated to ensure you're targeting the correct file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523617/how-to-unpack-an-asar-file)

Comment: ye, my app.asar is a blank index.html, I tried everything about the path and no sucess

Comment: @Collaxd did you find any solution? I'm facing same issue

Comment: actually I'm using `npm create electron-vite` [this](https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-react) @SwapnilSoni

Comment: Thanks @Collaxd actually I figured it out. This app needs either HashRouter or MemoryRouter. BrowserRouter wont work in this electron app case

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the [Electron-Vue](https://evite.netlify.app/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-electron-vite-project) project documentation.

```
npm create @quick-start/electron
```

I did all for you. And  it supports **Javascript**

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing an issue with electron builder but I debugged it and checked there is no relevant path attached to the build folder of Vite.
I have added the base property and set it to *"./"* and after building that electron+react+vite project it's working like a charm.

after changes vite.config.ts looks like this

```
export default defineConfig({
  base:'./',
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting started with a new electron project this will be a great help

https://electron-vite.org/

run :
`pnpm create @quick-start/electron`
and follow the instructions and pick react as framework to setup your electron app.