# How to convert a Node.js app to exe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Simply put, how do I compile/create and "exe" file that when you click on it, it will open console for you and type in the node "something"

There is a question about this regarding batch, but I really don't want to do anything batch because then you have to deal with filepaths, installing node... etc. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Comment: I actually took the time said "There is a question about this regarding batch". Did you even read the question? What the hell

Comment: Yes I read. Did you read the answers there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nexe says it will create a single executable out of your node.js apps.

https://github.com/nexe/nexe

Comment: don't really understand how I am supposed to do require?

Answer (score 0):

You can boundle electron application

Write in html, css, js and distribute to any platform

http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/