# Exe for Api rest - node js

Tags: node.js, rest, exe, obfuscation

Edit:
I am not asking for the api to return an executable, I want to protect the source code of the api, wherever it is installed

I'm starting with node js and I want to make an api, that's why there is no problem, but I wonder what possibility there is to make that api and give a client that obfuscated code or an exe,

I ask: It is better to obfuscate the code or generate an exe
Is there another alternative where the user does not have the code?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: If an API returned to me executable code, I would never use the API

Comment: I am not asking for the api to return an executable, I want to protect the source code of the api, wherever it is installed

Comment: In that more clear case, I know there's a few (infancy stage) modules that produce .exe files from a node app, but there's severe limitations. I'm sure there's code obfuscators in there as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few modules that achieve this,

https://jscrambler.com/ (paid)

or Free Alternative would be

https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But in performance they recommend creating the exe or obfuscate?