# Convert Node js project to Executable file

Tags: node.js, exec, nodes, exe, node-webkit

I have created Node js project, but my client requirement is to get its exe file so that he can run it without installing node.
Kindly help me to create node.js project into its executable file i.e exe file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Comment: Hi @YannickMeeus Issue you mentioned is for desktop app. But I have web app which has index.js as starting point instead of index.html.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have already solved your problem, but the question is not marked as resolved.

You can use a packer, I prefer to use BoxedApp Packer. This program can "convert" your Node js application into an executable file.
You just have to start the packer, select the file with your application, select the name of the output file and build. An executable file is ready. Enjoy!
It works with *.html and *js

Example: 
https://www.boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/usecases/pack_node_webkit_app_into_single_exe.html

Comment: You can use MoleBox also

Comment: If you use BoxedApp Packer or another similar packer, the exe file has small size. What is definitely a plus