# How to convert a vanilla node server into a executable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, window

I want to make a node .exe file that runs in the background.

I'm not using third npm packages, but the server is using these modules:

- FS (File System)
- Exec (Child Process)
- HTTP (Server)

The Exec triggers a batch file that opens a console.exe program.

Is there a way to bundle this up into a single .exe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an npm package called `pkg`. You can install it with

```
npm i pkg -g
```

Then you can convert your node project into an exe (macos and linux too) using:

```
pkg (yourfile).js
```

You can put the batch file with your packaged node exe to run it.

**EDIT**:

I misunderstood the question before, but to do this, you need to use a generator file. Unfourtunately it wont work for your binary files, but if you want use text files, you can do something like:

Create a file structure like this:

```
src/
  generator/
    generate.js
  asset.txt
  app.js
  makefile
```

in your makefile, put

```
.PHONY: all
all:
  node generator/generate.js
  pkg app.js
```

and in generate.js you can have something like:

```
fs.readFile("asset.txt", (e, data) => {
  fs.writeFile("assets.js", `
    var asset_txt = \`${data}\`
  `);
});
```

and in your app.js, require the assets.js file. It may be a messy solution, but I don't think there is a really good way.

Comment: I try this one, but the assets are not included, I had to put the .exe file next to the rest of the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package: [Nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe)

Comment: You can read this tutorial too:  https://dev.to/jochemstoel/bundle-your-node-app-to-a-single-executable-for-windows-linux-and-osx-2c89