# How to compile node.js server application to executable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

I have server oriented application which using puppeteer and express. Also I use private fields with new "hash" syntax in classes. Is it possible to compile such application to binary executable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Comment: @DickensAS  Is there any solution that works like pkg? I don't want to check each solution so that I ask here. I was trying to ask question in another way but question was banned by admins because of rule to not recommend tools and libraries.

Comment: is it a desktop application GUI or a server background application ?

Comment: @DickensAS It is desktop server-like application that uses web-browser as view.

Comment: still not getting your type of application, but I can give one solution which is `Electron` -- https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: @DickensAS Application has 2 layers:

1. Crawler that works in background and aggregates data, saves to sqlite.
2. Express as application server. Using ejs templates provides GUI for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools like [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) that can compile your node.js application to a standalone executable.

Comment: Problem with `pkg` is that it does not support private fields syntax.

Comment: Well then transpile your project with something like babel first and then compile it.

Comment: Ok but i take a look at your solution. I'll let you know about result, if they will not close thread.

Comment: After battle with configuring proper binaries, and node versions finally it works.