# possible way to use firebase-admin with Deno

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, deno

Since Deno has been released stable build just a few days ago, Is there a possible way to use firebase-admin with Deno?

Comment: check this repo, no guarantee that its working since its 10 months old: https://github.com/denoserverless/firebase-auth-rest, it might just give you idea how to start.

Comment: This question should be directed to the Firebase community.

Comment: https://deno.land/x/firestore_store@v2.0.2-rerelease Try this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of this post, both Google documentation and Firebase repositories have no Deno support.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

https://github.com/firebase?q=firebase-admin

Maybe they are already working on it, I can't know. You can reach out to them and do a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) and ask how you can help.

Answer (score 2):

As @Evandro Pomatti pointed out, there is no official support from the firebase team as a native Deno module. However, **NPM modules can be used within a Deno codebase**, so why not just use the existing `firebase-admin` codebase?

see [How to use npm module in DENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno)

```js
import { createRequire } from 'https://deno.land/std/node/module.ts';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const text = await Deno.readTextFile('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');
const adminKey = JSON.parse(text);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(adminKey),
    databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com'
});

const db = admin.database();
const ref = db.ref('restricted_access/secret_document');
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Since Deno is a secure runtime by default, reading files require explicit permissions using the `--allow-read` command

```sh
deno run --allow-read=node_modules myfile.ts
```

Comment: Does this work ?

Comment: I tried doing something similar using Deno, unfortunately it errors with a crypto error. See https://github.com/ben-xD/push/pull/22/commits/4085b55f694ec47ee72f4ec80afba96d873d43fd. Switched to Node in that MR.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Firebase is supported via few polyfills. https://deno.com/deploy/docs/tutorial-firebase

But you might hit a roadblock. Let me if that works for you.

Comment: That’s firebase 8x, but they’re now on 9x and it has better ES module support. Might be a better choice and might “just work”.