# How to use Google OAuth with Deno js?

Tags: javascript, oauth, deno

Is there some libraries or modules for Google OAuth in Deno.js? I am trying to impelemnt google login on my web application and use this google account for uploading youtube videos in deno.js.

I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a generic solution for OAuth doesn't exist yet. However, if you can override the default implementation, you can try [authlete_deno_fen_oauth_server](https://deno.land/x/authlete_deno_fen_oauth_server) third party module.

There is a [generic oauth2 module](https://deno.land/x/oauth2) but not available at the moment.

If the above option doesn't work, try **using an npm module in deno** as described in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno/62252798) and follow [this medium article](https://medium.com/authpack/easy-google-auth-with-node-js-99ac40b97f4c) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [youtube-deno](https://github.com/akshgpt7/youtube-deno). I haven't used it myself, but it seems like it provides a good interface for communicating with the Youtube API with deno.

---

Here's an example from the readme:

```js
// A simple example to call the search_list() function and log the response json.
import { YouTube } from "https://x.nest.land/youtube-deno@0.0.6/mod.ts";

let obj = new YouTube("your-api-key-here", false);

obj.search_list({part: "snippet", q: "the coding train"}).then(function(response){
 console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The module [deno-oauth2-client](https://github.com/cmd-johnson/deno-oauth2-client) works well, it's small and easy to use.

Another library, [Dashport](https://github.com/oslabs-beta/dashport), aims to be like Passport.js for Deno. I had a bit of trouble with their example code, so I put [a fork of Dashport](https://github.com/ultracodemonkey/dashport) here with a few fixes and some example code.

I put together a couple of examples for these OAuth2 libraries in Deno:

- [deno-oauth2-client example](https://gitlab.com/sswam/deno-auth-test)
- [dashport example](https://gitlab.com/sswam/dashport-test)