# deno import lodash from deno.land/x

Tags: import, lodash, deno

I haven't been able to find the right syntax/URL to import Lodash in a Deno program.
I tried this:

```js
import _ from 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.js';
```

That gives the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.js' does not provide an export named 'default'".

Then I tried this:

```js
import * as lodash from 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.js';
```

That seems to give me an empty module object.

I'd like to see an example of accessing any function of Lodash from a Deno program.

Comment: https://medium.com/@tokenchingy/how-to-use-lodash-with-deno-fff9d11b8c5f

Comment: Really simple solution: https://github.com/michael-spengler/deno-lodash

It does all the boilerplate for you, and adds NO extra code :) Much easier to use with Deno

Answer (score 9):

So after a little experiment, I find two ways to import `lodash` into `deno` environment.

#### 1. Treat deno as a plain browser environment

```js
import "https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.19/dist/lodash.js";

// now `_` is imported in the global variable, which in deno is `self`
const _ = (self as any)._;

console.log(_.chunk([1, 2, 3], 2)); // --> [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3 ] ]
```

#### 2. Fake node functionality in deno

In deno std, there is a node module:

> This module is meant to have a compatibility layer for the NodeJS standard library.

```js
import { createRequire } from "https://deno.land/std@0.86.0/node/module.ts";

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

// seems require don't known how to import file from web, 
// so you must download it in your local filesystem.
const _ = require("./lodash.js");  

console.log(_.chunk([1, 2, 3], 2)); // --> [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3 ] ]
```

#### Add type info

This is what I found, it is a bit cumbersome.

1. Download types info from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash
2. Edit every import from `xxx` to `xxx.d.ts`. For example: in the file `common/common.d.ts`:

```js
// before
import _ = required("../index");
declare module "../index" {
/* ... */

// after
import _ from "../index.d.ts";
declare module "../index.d.ts" {
/* ... */
```

3. Now you can import the type info and use it

```js
import type Lodash from "./types/lodash/index.d.ts";

const _: typeof Lodash = (self as any)._;

// now _ is typed
```

[a vscode screenshot to demonstrate type info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GETat.png)

---

Here are some snippet in the source file of `lodash`, which I think related to import.

```js
  // Detect which environment you're currently in:

  /** Detect free variable `global` from Node.js. */
  var freeGlobal = typeof global == 'object' && global && global.Object === Object && global;

  /** Detect free variable `self`. */
  var freeSelf = typeof self == 'object' && self && self.Object === Object && self;

  /** Used as a reference to the global object. */
  var root = freeGlobal || freeSelf || Function('return this')();

  /** Detect free variable `exports`. */
  var freeExports = typeof exports == 'object' && exports && !exports.nodeType && exports;

  /** Detect free variable `module`. */
  var freeModule = freeExports && typeof module == 'object' && module && !module.nodeType && module;

  /** Detect the popular CommonJS extension `module.exports`. */
  var moduleExports = freeModule && freeModule.exports === freeExports;

  /** Detect free variable `process` from Node.js. */
  var freeProcess = moduleExports && freeGlobal.process;

  // ...
```

```js
  // And how `lodash` exports its functionality:

  // Some AMD build optimizers, like r.js, check for condition patterns like:
  if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd == 'object' && define.amd) {
    // Expose Lodash on the global object to prevent errors when Lodash is
    // loaded by a script tag in the presence of an AMD loader.
    // See http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch for more details.
    // Use `_.noConflict` to remove Lodash from the global object.
    root._ = _;

    // Define as an anonymous module so, through path mapping, it can be
    // referenced as the "underscore" module.
    define(function() {
      return _;
    });
  }
  // Check for `exports` after `define` in case a build optimizer adds it.
  else if (freeModule) {
    // Export for Node.js.
    (freeModule.exports = _)._ = _;
    // Export for CommonJS support.
    freeExports._ = _;
  }
  else {
    // Export to the global object.
    root._ = _;
  }

  // ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Use version in **es module**. More same questions see here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62252798/6733679

```js
import _ from 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.15-es/lodash.js';

console.log(_);
```

[image]

Comment: With this approach you don't get any types for lodash. Is there a way to add the types from `@types/lodash-es`? Ideally something simpler than KoalaYT's approach!

Answer (score 3):

As of [Deno 1.28](https://deno.com/blog/v1.28) this is significantly simpler:

```
// @deno-types="npm:@types/lodash"
import _ from "npm:lodash";
```

The first line is necessary to pull in the TypeScript types from DefinitelyTyped (`@types/lodash`). If you omit it, your lodash usage will be unsafe.

You can specify exact versions if you like:

```
// @deno-types="npm:@types/lodash@4.14.191"
import _ from "npm:lodash@4.17.21";
```

Of if you're collecting dependencies in a `deps.ts` file, something like this will do:

```
// @deno-types="npm:@types/lodash"
import {default as ld} from "npm:lodash";
export const _ = ld;
```