# How can I get socket.io to work with deno?

Tags: socket.io, deno, unpkg

My aim is to get socket.io to work with deno. Deno does have a standard library for web sockets, but that does not have a fail-over.
I think it is possible to use the UNPKG service to use an NPM package in you deno program, but I seem to get the syntax wrong for importing socket.io:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts";
import {Socket} from "https://unpkg.com/browse/socket.io@3.0.1/dist/index.d.ts";

new Worker(new URL("worker.js", import.meta.url).href, { type: "module" });
const server = serve({ port: 3001 });
const app = new Application();
const io = Socket(3001);

// serve index page
if (req.url === "/") {
  req.respond({
    status: 200,
    body: await Deno.open("./public/index.html"),
  });
}

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // either with send()
  socket.send("Hello!");

  // or with emit() and custom event names
  socket.emit("greetings", "Hey!", { "ms": "jane" }, Buffer.from([4, 3, 3, 1]));

  // handle the event sent with socket.send()
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  // handle the event sent with socket.emit()
  socket.on("salutations", (elem1, elem2, elem3) => {
    console.log(elem1, elem2, elem3);
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
error: An unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module.
  Specifier: https://unpkg.com/browse/socket.io@3.0.1/dist/index.d.ts
  MediaType: Unknown
```

Comment: try the url without "browse": https://unpkg.com/socket.io@3.0.1/dist/index.d.ts

Comment: Did you make it work with Deno?

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you are importing a `.d.ts` file, which is a declaration file and essentially you can't run any code from - it's purely to support types.

Instead you should replace `index.d.ts` with `index.js`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import Socket from 'https://cdn.esm.sh/v9/socket.io@3.0.3/esnext/socket.io.js';
```

As @Indecisive said, `you are importing a .d.ts file`.

You can use @Marcos Casagrande: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821141/6250402 (remember install `socket.io` module with npm)

Or use `https://deno.land/std@0.79.0/ws/mod.ts`