# Why am I getting a 500 response when using Deno and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, deno

I have the following code...

```
// test.mjs
import {MongoClient} from "https://dev.jspm.io/mongodb";
console.log("Loaded");
```

But when I run `deno run ./test.mjs` I get...

```
Download https://dev.jspm.io/npm:require_optional@1.0.1/index.dew.js
error: Import 'https://dev.jspm.io/npm:require_optional@1.0.1/index.dew.js' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
    at https://dev.jspm.io/npm:require_optional@1?dew:1:0
```

What I am missing? I am using ChromeOs so basically Linux.

Comment: read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno) about using npm modules in Deno. There's also a [Mongo Client for Deno](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.21.2)

Comment: Deno doesn't support node module. Node polyfill for Deno is still incomplete,