# using mapbox-gl with deno

Tags: typescript, mapbox-gl-js, deno

I'am trying to use mapbox with deno

Actually i'am trying this :

```
import mapboxgl from 'https://dev.jspm.io/mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken =  "toto";

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
  center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
  });
```

based on :
[How to use npm module in DENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno)

using jspm
I have too many error when i try i have a :

```
esModuleInterop, module, target
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type '{}'.
mapboxgl.accessToken =  "toto";
         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    at file:///home/bussiere/Workspace/GreatParis/templateV2/source/deno/Mapbox/map.ts:10:10

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'Map' does not exist on type '{}'.
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                       ~~~
    at file:///home/bussiere/Workspace/GreatParis/templateV2/source/deno/Mapbox/map.ts:12:24
```

i've also tried :

```
import {  mapboxgl } from "./../../libs/mapbox/2_1_1/mapbox-gl.js";

mapboxgl.accessToken =  "toto";

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
  center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
  });
```

But i have a :

```
Unsupported compiler options in "templateV2/source/deno/Mapbox/tsconfig.json".
  The following options were ignored:
    esModuleInterop, module, target
Bundle file:///home/bussiere/Workspace/GreatParis/templateV2/source/deno/Mapbox/map.ts
Emit "../compiled/map.js" (1.45MB)
error: Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: unreachable
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:336403)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:341096)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:339419)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:339781)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:336272)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:268321)
    at minify (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:253183)
    at minify (https://deno.land/x/minifier@v1.1.1/wasm.js:98:14)
    at minify (https://deno.land/x/minifier@v1.1.1/mod.ts:27:10)
    at https://deno.land/x/minifier@v1.1.1/cli.ts:53:3
```

here is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["dom","es2015","DOM"],                    /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "strictNullChecks": false,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
 
  }
}
```

Does anyone manage to use mapbox-gl with deno ?

Regards

Comment: Deno is a server-side runtime, while `mapbox-gl` is a browser package for rendering to the DOM. Even if you could get the types working, I don't believe you'll have any luck actually doing anything with the result.

Comment: For what it's worth, the error you're seeing when using JSPM was introduced in Deno 1.5.0, likely by the switch to a new tsc infrastructure internally and/or enabling `isolatedModules` by default (see the [changelog](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.5.0)). You can run that code with 1.4.0 or earlier, just do `deno upgrade --version 1.4.0`.

Answer (score 2):

In its package.json `mapbox-gl-js` describes itself as "a WebGL interactive maps library". It expects to run in a browser, with access to the DOM and WebGL (a technology to render graphics efficiently).

There can be two reasons I can think of to want to run it with Deno:

1. Adding map visualizations to a webapp that already uses Deno. In this case, it's easy. You don't want Deno to run mapbox-gl. What you really want is that Deno serves webpages with some static javascript that will be executed in the browser (not the server) and run `mapbox-gl`. To go this way, configure Deno to serve th HTML in this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/
2. Programatically generating raster images (PNG, ...) of maps. For instance you might want to save a map of a city automatically from its latitude and longitude, with all the style and options that mapbox-gl provides. This is usually called a "static map API". You don't necessarily need to run it yourself, [here is Mapbox's documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/) for this API (50,000 free / month). If your really want to run it yourself, see below.

## Running `mapbox-gl` on a server

Using `mapbox-gl-js` without a browser would require you to emulate the DOM and WebGL. But there is actually a simpler way generate static mapx: `mapbox-gl-native`. It expects rendering libraries that are easier (and more performant?) to provide on a server.

One project that accomplishes that is [tileserver-gl](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl). Its source code is quite small, you could get guidance from that. Part of the problem of using `mapbox-gl-native` will be to install and configure its dependencies. Learn about it  [from tileserver-gl dependencies](https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#native-dependencies).

You could reproduce `tileserver-gl` in Deno, even reuse some of its source files if the license fits. But you might not need to! Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could just start `tileserver-gl` with Docker, and use Deno to request static map images from its [API endpoints](https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints.html#static-images).