# How to import Typeorm in deno?

Tags: database, typescript, node-modules, typeorm, deno

I am trying to require typeorm into deno but I cannot use it.
I have looked at the documentation but it was not clear about how to imported in deno
IS there a way to use it within deno env?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use npm module in DENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno)

Answer (score 0):

[Deno supports ES modules](https://deno.land/manual#comparison-to-nodejs) and does not support `require()` statements. If you are trying to use a valid ES module, then it should work with Deno. Many packages on npm (including `typeorm`) [don't currently provide ES modules](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6974). Here is a Deno-related tracking issue in the typeorm repo:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6123