# How can I use a NPM package within a Deno app?

Tags: typescript, npm, deno, alpha-vantage

I want to know how can I use this [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alphavantage-ts) inside my Deno application?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @mfulton26: Nothing as I am new in Deno. I searched to see if I can find this library between third party libraries on deno.land but couldn't find it. I don't know how to import it inside a Deno application.

Comment: I think there's a fairly straight forward, generic answer for this (which I've posted below) but in case you have trouble getting useful answers to questions in the future I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); sharing specifics about what online web searching yielded you but where it fell short for you gives others insights into more specific issues you may be facing with which they may be able to help you with; my best wishes!

Comment: Be cautious about using transpilation service providers like the ones mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71243737/438273). While they do effort to shim/patch/polyfill and rewrite specifiers to be compatible with Deno's module system (ESM), this is not always possible (e.g if the module uses a Node-exclusive API), and so the burden is on you to audit the transpilation result with every source code revision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use npm module in DENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find answers to most, if not all, of your questions in Deno's manual:

5. [Using npm/Node.js code | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.19.0/npm_nodejs)

Specifically 5.1 [Packages from CDNs | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.19.0/npm_nodejs/cdns).

I've used [Skypack](https://www.skypack.dev/) but I hear other CDNs work well too (e.g. [JSPM](https://jspm.io/)).