# nodejs app as Windows Service, just with an exe

Tags: node.js

It is possible to build a nodejs app as a windows service but let the user install this service only by an installer or exe?
I know node-windows, but for this the target system must have nodejs installed.

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/compile-your-nodejs-application-into-a-exe-file/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)