# How to make an executable (.exe) for nodeJs project having files in ES6 format?

Tags: node.js, executable, nexe

I'm working on a project which requires my code to be converted into an executable .exe format to make it run on windows. However I can't find any method or a solution to convert my nodeJs codebase which is in **ES6 format** into an executable.

I came across few solution such as **nexe and pkg**, but neither of them supports ES6 -  these two packages expects my codebase to be in a ES5 format which has **require** in it instead of **import**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Comment: Hi @Jay, thanks for the thread you shared, but the solution mentioned in the thread you shared has a lot of manual stuffs to do, but since I need to automate the process of making builds I'm afraid I cannot proceed to use that. I posted the solution that worked well for me here. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After surfing around a bit on google, git issues and discussion, I found a solution on pkg's discussion thread. The second solution on the below image works well for my application and use case. https://github.com/vercel/pkg/discussions/1388

[image: solution]