# How to pack a Node JS project to .exe file while using packages such as opencv4nodejs and robotjs

Tags: node.js, node-ffi, robotjs

I wrote a demo to create screenshot by robotjs, find the location of a target button by opencv4nodejs and click it. As description above, robotjs, opencv4nodejs and node-ffi was used in this script. I also want to pack it as .exe file so we can distribute it and let other user run it without installing Node JS enviroment. I used pkg to create .exe file for this project and error occured when I run this .exe file:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1206
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
^
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\?\C:\...\Pkg\cache\example\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\build\Release\opencv4nodejs.node
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1206:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object. (E:\Project\web\Demo\open\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\lib\cv.js:58:8)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This script can be run perfectly in development environments. I am not sure what happenned. Please help me.

Environments:
Node JS v10.x
opencv4nodejs latest
node-ffi latest
robotjs latest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)