# Make an executable application using node.js

Tags: node.js, executable

I created a node.js backend that runs on PORT 6543 and serves some APIs. Now what I want is that make an executable file of that application and share that .exe file with my customers.

My customers will install this application so when they use my website it will hit user's local backend that is running in the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)