# Is it possible to secure node.js code for download an run

Tags: node.js, security

Basically we are using node.js on a raspi. So every customer gets a raspi or we install the app on the requested device. To make things easier, we would like to provide the app as download.

I started my search to read following:

[How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Understanding it right, there is no possibility to secure / hide the code. It seems, that it is allways possible to access the node.js code.

Is there a way to "compile" the node.js code in an exe file with the code not accessable?

Happy for any information / new starting point

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language; you will always have some risk of reversibility varying only in the degree of difficulty to do so. What risks are you trying to prevent, exactly?

Comment: We would like to pack our node.js server into a single file / container for download. The  downloaded code must be secured / not accessable. The node.js server in the file / container can be started via the console. With other words, we are looking for a way to compile our node.js server to an exe file. Is this possible?

Comment: "*not accessable*" What risks would you be introducing if your client code was revealed? There may be ways to rearchitect your design to mitigate them.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody mentioned https://github.com/vercel/pkg yet, so that may help you there

Comment: From the readme in the linked repository: “*While compiling to bytecode does not make your source code 100% secure, it does add a small layer of security/privacy/obscurity to your source code.*”  This does not fully meet the OP’s requirement “*to "compile" the node.js code in an exe file with the code not accessable*”